# How is the performance when using multiple / double / conditional CSS selectors? For example .hello1.hellob

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

When reading around the web concerning CSS performance, I often find a list of what selectors are more efficient than others. For example:

http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

```
#main-navigation {   }      /* ID (Fastest) */
body.home #page-wrap {   }  /* ID */
.main-navigation {   }      /* Class */
ul li a.current {   }       /* Class *
ul {   }                    /* Tag */
ul li a {  }                /* Tag */
* {   }                     /* Universal (Slowest) */
#content [title='home']     /* Universal */
```

My question is, how is the performance when using selectors that require double selectors, for example:

```
.class-one.class-two {
}
```

If we were to put these selectors in the performance list above, where would they be?

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer - there are so many ways you can combine simple selectors that it would simply be too tedious if at all possible to test them all reliably, let alone sort them by performance.

Comment: How would you even test this? Is there a CSS-rendering-time variable somewhere in the browser that one can access through some API?

Comment: What he said. But my guess is that this one with two class names would end up between the one with one class name and the one with three elements and a class name.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FWriting_Efficient_CSS#How_the_Style_System_Matches_Rules

Visit this link. It might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be so paranoid about that. More important is to have a good and clean code, avoiding hacks.
But there are some basic rules:

```
#main-navigation {   }      /* Never style ID's directly, use classes instead*/
body.home #page-wrap {   }  /* If you ever have to style ID's, do it directly, they are unique and doesn't need any selector. You're just wasting bytes */
.main-navigation {   }      /* No problem at all, but try to be more abstract. a class should not be so specific, try to reuse code as much as you can.*/
ul li a.current {   }       /* You should optimize this, you could use just ul .current. Try to use as little selectors as you can, it'll have good performance and will be easier to deal with. Try to use just 3 selectors at the max, so you''l have a good performance and clean code. */
ul {   }                    /* No problem here */
* {   }                     /* You'll won't have any serious problem if you use with caution. Properties like border-box are a good use of it. Anything that you have to set globally in your stylesheet is welcome to use it. */
#content [title='home']     /* Same as *. Don't overdo and you're good to go. */
```

More important is to have the cleaner code as possible. Try to avoid excessive overrides, unused code, too much selectors, repeated code and hacks. A good thing is to use [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) and [BEM](http://bem.info/). If you use a framework, try to use something like [inuit.css](https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css) that sticks to good practice and all.

Keep in mind that even smartphones are pretty powerful today and as long as you don't over do using a lot of animations, unoptimized code, a lot of javascript you should have no real problem.

Ps.: If you use animations, stick to CSS3 transitions and animations because there's a good chance that they will be GPU accelerated and will get better perfomance.

Answer (score 0):

Besides "Writing efficient CSS" Mozilla article, you may also be interested in the talk "Faster HTML and CSS: Layout Engine Internals for Web Developers" by Googlers http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2_6bGNZ7bA

In general, a browsers reads each selector from right to left and then "calculates" if it is applicable to a current DOM node. This is why the selectors ending with tags or with a lot of cascade cause performance problems, especially on dynamically re-rendered pages.

This can be avoided if following BEM CSS recommendations about **independent** CSS blocks. http://bem.info/method/definitions/#IndependentCSS